# OpenAI API error: Why do I still get the "No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils';" error after I upgraded the OpenAI package and Python?

Tags: python, openai-api

I've been trying to play around with OpenAI embeddings, but got quickly stuck on environment configuration. I've looked at other similar problems questions here and have followed the answers posted there, but I'm still being thrown an error that package does not exist.

The code is primitive:

```
import pandas as pd
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
```

Where output is:

```
PS C:\Users\username> python openai.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\openai.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openai
  File "C:\Users\username\openai.py", line 3, in <module>
    from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'; 'openai' is not a package
```

All dependencies should be in order:

```
PS C:\Users\username> pip show openai
Name: openai
Version: 0.27.8
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License:
Location: c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, requests, tqdm
Required-by:

PS C:\Users\username> python --version
Python 3.10.6

PS C:\Users\username> pip --version
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
```

The openai folder in `python310\lib\site-packages\` contains `embedding_utils.py`.

I've tried uninstalling openai, and reinstalling it. I've also tried to install `openai[embeddings]`, but none of the options have worked. The other answers have hinted that this may be a problem with Python version, but to me it looks as if everything is OK with Python version as well.

Comment: do not name your python script the same as a package.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't name the file `openai.py`.**

You said you upgraded both the OpenAI Python package and Python, but the error persists.

One common mistake people make is naming the file `openai.py`. It'll cause the `No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'; 'openai' is not a package` error even though you upgraded everything.